# Compartilhar dados entre components Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu tenho um component de Navbar que fica na raiz do projeto, e tenho do lado desse component
um outro que é uma parte.Ex:

```
navbar
componenet1[
    component2
    component3
    component4[
        component5
        component6
    ]

]
```

Preciso passar um dado do component 6 pra navbar, mas apenas quando eu entro na rota desse component, alguem tem uma ideia de como fazer isso
para me ajudar.

Comment: não compensa fazer um service pra  isso? por que se for fazer Output até o nivel do navbar vai ficar mt feio

Comment: O foda é que eu preciso não refazer requisição, ai eu até tenho service pra isso. O problema é a verificação de rota nesse caso;

Comment: da uma pesquisada em SnapShot do angular.

Comment: Pode exprimentar sempre utilizar store para a sua aplicaçao isso vai te premitir aceder aos dados em difrentes partes da aplicação (ex:https://ngrx.io/guide/store)

Answer (score 1):

Tem duas formas principais de compartilhar um estado entre dois componentes que não tem relação de pai/filho. A primeira seria com behavior subject com um service injetado nos dois componentes outra forma seria por um gerenciador de estado como o [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) que segue o padrão redux.

**Exemplo com behavior subject:**

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { Data } from '../entities/data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<SnapshotSelection>(new Data());
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatedDataSelection(data: Data){
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

Seu Componente

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

dataService.data.subscribe(data => {
// use os dados aqui
})

dataService.updateData(newData);// para atualizar os dados
```

**Fonte:** https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc

Comment: Porque usou o decorator `@Injectable()`? Pelo que sei ele é usado quando se injeta um serviço dentro do outro! Essa linha é uma injeção?  `private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<SnapshotSelection>(new Data());`

Comment: O @Injectable() significa que o angular vai lidar com o dependency injection pra vc, então vc pode iniciar esse service em qualquer construtor seja de um componente ou outro serviço que o angular injeta ele pra vc. Nesse caso vc injeta o serviço nos dois componentes que vc quer comunicar.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, eu preciso que o dado vá para a navbar apenas quando eu entrar na rota la do component 6, o problema está ai, não tenho um evento que verifica se a rota mudou, isso que está mais me atrapalhando

Comment: vc pode usar o dataService.updateData(newData); no init do component 6 e usar um if no navbar pra saber se veio o dado ainda ou não.

Comment: Por acaso essa informação veio deste artigo: https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc ?

Comment: não lembro agora mas tem vários artigos sobre behaviorSubject