# Passar valor para outra página em angular

Tags: html, angular

Bom dia!! Em determinada página eu tenho um botão que pega código e nome de um cliente e preciso passar essa informação para um input de outra página:

**Página da função que pega código e nome**

```
<tr *ngFor="let pesquisas of pesquisa">
              <td class="text-center">{{pesquisas.Codigo}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{pesquisas.Nome}}</td>
              <th>
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="PegarValores(pesquisas.Codigo, pesquisas.Nome)">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green;"></i>  Iniciar
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>
```

**Página que quero receber as informações(input)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Cliente:</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control small" formControlName="codigoCliente" required>
        <input type="text" class="form-control size" formControlName="nomeCliente">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="height:30px;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search a"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Ps:Estou recebendo as informações na função PegarValores(ao clicar, o console mostra o cliente que estou selecionando)

Comment: O melhor e usar um serviço compartilhado entre os dois componentes. Usando algo com um BehaviorSubject para compartilhar essas informações.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305588/compartilhar-dados-entre-components-angular-6/305989#305989

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema, abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem duas formas principais de compartilhar um estado entre dois componentes que não tem relação de pai/filho. A primeira seria com behavior subject com um service injetado nos dois componentes outra forma seria por um gerenciador de estado como o [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) que segue o padrão redux.

**Exemplo com behavior subject:**

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { Data } from '../entities/data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<SnapshotSelection>(new Data());
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatedDataSelection(data: Data){
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

Seu Componente

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

dataService.data.subscribe(data => {
// use os dados aqui
})

dataService.updateData(newData);// para atualizar os dados
```

**Fonte:** https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc