# Como acessar retorno de um objeto EventEmitter criado a partir do http.get

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho um serviço que realiza um get em um determinado endereço.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {

  private person: Observable<Person>;
  personBroadcast = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPersonByCode(code: number): Observable<Person> {
    this.person = this.http.get<Person>(environment.urlHumanResourceService + 'api/person/code/' + code);
    this.personBroadcast.emit(this.person);
    return this.person;
  }
}
```

Estou usando ele no seguinte componente:

```
export class PatientComponent implements OnInit {

  private person: Person;

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onEnter(value: number) { this.getPersonByCode(value);  }

  public getPersonByCode(code: number) {
    this.personService.getPersonByCode(code).subscribe((data: Person) => {
      this.person = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Até esse ponto está tudo funcionando como esperado, porém preciso utilizar alguns dados do resultado desse get em outro componente. Pesquisando achei a solução de usar um EventEmitter para comunicar o resultado do get.

```
export class AttendanceComponent implements OnInit {

  private attendance: Attendance;
  private person: Person;

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personService.personBroadcast.subscribe((data: Person) => {
      this.person = data;
    });
  }

  newClinicalAppointment(observation: string) {
    console.log(this.person);
    this.attendance = new Attendance(
      null,
      null,
      this.person,
      new Date,
      AttendanceTypes.ClinicalAppointment,
      observation
    );
  }
}
```

Testando estou recebendo um objeto Observable e não consigo pelo subscribe ter acesso aos dados que esperava. Testei passando um objeto criado na mão no emit() e nesse caso obtive sucesso.

O que foi feito de errado? A solução que estou usando para esse problema é a melhor abordagem?

Comment: Event emmiter e de um componente filho pra um pai pra fazer essa comunicação entre serviços melhor usar Behavior Subject

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305588/compartilhar-dados-entre-components-angular-6/305989#305989