# Alterar atributo de um componente em outro componente no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu tenho dois componentes:

Registro e Login

No RegistroComponent eu tenho essa âncora:

```
<a id="titleClient">Already have a account? Click here</a>
```

Eu preciso que quando o usuário clique na ancora altere no componente de login o atributo da minha classe "already_client" para true:

```
export class LoginComponentimplements OnInit {
  already_client: boolean
  ...
}
```

Eu pensei em fazer com input property mas eu uso o router-outlet para mostrar os componentes, eu não consigo usar, por exemplo:

Como posso fazer?

Obrigado

**@Edit:**

Como funcionou para mim:

Meu componente login:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.handleSubscriptions()
  }

  public handleSubscriptions() {
    this.subscription = this.registrarService.params.subscribe(
      action => {
        if(action !== undefined){
          this.usuario.cliente= action.action
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Registrar component:

```
  setPossuiConta(){
    this.registrarService.setParameters(true);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

Serviço:

```
 private cliente: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({} as any);
  public params = this.cliente.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  public setParameters(possui_conta: boolean) {
    this.cliente.next({action: possui_conta});
  }
```

Comment: Você deve passar o valor para o componente login usando o decorator [@Input](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), por favor forneca mais detalhes a sua pergunta

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305588/compartilhar-dados-entre-components-angular-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um service, adicione o Subject e também um método para emitir o valor.

```
alreadyClientChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  changeValue(){
    this.alreadyClientChange.next(true);
  }
```

Injete o serviço no RegistroComponent e adicione um método para quando o usuário clicar no link

```
meuMetodo(){
 myService.changeValue();
}
```

Injete o serviço também em LoginComponent e se inscreva para obter e alterar o valor de `already_client`

```
ngOnInit() {
  myService.alreadyClientChange.subscribe(res => {
    already_client = res;
  });
}
```